# Render native OpenGL code in Android Widget?

Tags: android, opengl-es, native

Is it possible to:

1. render arbitrary OpenGL code on an application's widget view in Android, and
2. drive an Android widget with native C++ code (instead of Java)?

<sub>*Motivation: I have access to an Android native OpenGL application that I'd like to modify to work as a widget. Before I undertake this endeavor, I hoped to hear directly if it was absolutely possible (maybe even with a pointer to a code sample), or absolutely impossible.*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout):

> App Widget layouts are based on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget.

For OpenGL you need [`TextureView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) or [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and neither are supported by `RemoteViews`.